# Delete table row django rest framework

Tags: django, datatables, django-rest-framework

I have a two buttons in my datatable that I'm trying to utilize to delete and edit an row.

In my `ModelViewSet` I'm trying to do something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters, status
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route
from rest_framework.response import Response

from beaconpro.company.models.organization_model import OrganizationModel
from beaconpro.company.restapi.serializers.organization_model_serializer import OrganizationModelSerializer
from beaconpro.company.restapi.pagination import StandardResultsOffsetPagination


class OrganizationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = OrganizationModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrganizationModelSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter)
    filter_fields = ('id', 'organization_name')
    ordering_fields = ('id', 'organization_name', 'delete_organization_name')
    search_fields = ('id', 'organization_name', 'delete_organization_name')
    pagination_class = StandardResultsOffsetPagination

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, args, kwargs)

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        organization = get_object_or_404(OrganizationModel, pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
        organization.delete()
        return super(OrganizationViewSet, self).destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)

    @detail_route(methods=['update'])
    def edit_organization_name(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    @detail_route(methods=['delete'])
    def delete_organization_name(self, request, pk):
        organization = get_object_or_404(OrganizationModel, pk=pk)
        organization.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

so I'm passing `delete_organization_name` into datatable using `data` to a button like this:

```
$('#searchCompanyList').DataTable( {
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    searchDelay: 1000,
    order: [[ 1, "desc" ]],
    orderMulti: false,
    pageLength: 10,
    ajax: {
      url: '/api/organization/',
      data: function(data) {
        data.limit = data.length;
        data.offset = data.start;
        data.search = data.search['value'];
        if (data.order[0]['dir'] == 'asc') {
            data.ordering = data.columns[data.order[0]['column']].name;
        } else {
            data.ordering = '-' + data.columns[data.order[0]['column']].name;
        }
      },
      dataFilter: function(data) {
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
        json.recordsTotal = json.count;
        json.recordsFiltered = json.count;
        json.data = json.results;
        return JSON.stringify( json ); // return JSON string
      }
    },
    columns: [
        {
            data: "organization_name",
            name: "organization_name"
        },
        {
            data: "edit_organization_name",
            render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                return '<a type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="' + data + '">Edit</a>';
            }
        },
        {
            data: "delete_organization_name",
            render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                return '<a type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="' + data + '">Remove</a>';
            }
        }
    ]

  });
```

now the `url` that I'm passing all the data to a datatable is `/api/organization/`, so I'm trying to construct a url to delete a row to be something like this

```
urlpatterns = [
url(
    r'^create-company/$',
    login_required(views.OrganizationCreateView.as_view(), login_url='/'),
    name='create-company'
),
url(
    r'^organization/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$',
    login_required(apiviews.OrganizationViewSet, login_url='/'),
    name='organization-edit'
),
url(
    r'^organization/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$',
    login_required(apiviews.OrganizationViewSet, login_url='/'),
    name='organization-delete'
)
```

]

but all I've got is this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/create-company/undefined
```

so the url is not good, and I'm failing to grasp how to configure this properly, so can anyone advice what to do and how to achieve that my button delete one table row.